# Django admin filter foreign key combobox

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin, django-1.11

I'm a django beginner, so the code might be basic or wrong, but anyway...
I have the following models:

```
 from django.db import models
    from django.conf import settings

    GRADE_CHOICES = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
        ('6', '6'),
        ('7', '7'),
        ('8', '8'),
        ('9', '9'),
        ('10', '10'),
    )
    class Professor(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __str__(self):
            rta = self.first_name+" "+self.last_name
            return rta

    class Student(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)

        def __str__(self):
            rta = self.first_name+" "+self.last_name
            return rta

    class Subject(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True)
        professors = models.ManyToManyField(Professor, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name

    class Grade(models.Model):
        value = models.CharField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES, max_length= 2)
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fk_grade')
        student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fk_student')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.value
```

To add a grade I need to select the subject and the student, so I want to filter the students based on the subject they belong to.
If the student is not in that subject he shouldn't appear in the list.

I'm using django 1.11 and python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `Grade`should not be related to a `Subject` and a `Student` but to a relationship between a `Subject` and a `Student`. Sometinhg like:

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    # ...

class Student(models.Model):
    # ...
    professors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Subject')


class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES, max_length= 2)
```